# “IndexError: tuple index out of range” as part of data flow template job

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Below is my python code which is absolutely working fine.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
import pickle
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    (p | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='select DISTINCT(REPLACE(MOBILE,"+91 ","91")) from `whr-asia-datalake-nonprod.WHR_DATALAKE.C4C_CONSUMER_RAW`',use_standard_sql=True))
       | 'read values' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.values())
       | 'CSV format' >> beam.Map(lambda row:'|'.join ("WHIRLPOOL|WHR|"+ str(column) +'|"'+"Hi, This msg is from Whirlpool DL" + '"' for column in row))
       | 'Write_to_GCS' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Valuefirst/WHR_MOBILE_CNSNT_REQ'+''+ str(current_date),file_name_suffix='.csv',header='SENDER_ID|SHORTCODE|MOBILE_NUM|CONSENT_MSG'))
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I modified the above code to add a new requirement of creating and empty ".done" file with every file created above. We added below function in our job to create an empty file

```
today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

def create_done(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    (p | 'Create .done File' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Valuefirst/Valuefirst'+''+str(current_date),file_name_suffix='.done'))
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    create_done()
```

However,as soon we add this new code for creating empty .done file, the script is failing with error as

input_tag = transform_node.inputs[0].tag
IndexError: tuple index out of range

I am not able to paste the full traceback of the error. Please let me know of this helps.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the full error traceback. Also make sure to post a [mre]

Comment: hello @Tomerikoo, sorry, The error that I am getting is "IndexError: tuple index out of range".

Comment: Sure, I got that from your title. It doesn't help much. Post the ***full traceback*** of the error

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thank you. I understand. I am new to this . Find below the error , not able to provide the entire error. Hope this helps   
    self.runner.run_transform(transform_node, options)
  File "/home/radhika_sharma_ibm/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 246, in run_transform
    return m(transform_node, options)
  File "/home/radhika_sharma_ibm/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 897, in run_ParDo
    input_tag = transform_node.inputs[0].tag
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: This is unreadable. Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Then, [edit] your question with all necessary information

Comment: hello @Tomerikoo, I did edit my question to after having read about " minimal reproducible example." Does this help? please advise. as mentioned earlier, not able to paste full error because of the limit. The last few lines of the error are   
  File "/home/radhika_sharma_ibm/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 897, in run_ParDo
    input_tag = transform_node.inputs[0].tag
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0):

WriteToText requires an input PCollection, but you are applying it directly to the Pipeline object.  You need a data source, like ReadFromText or Create, in order to run your pipeline.

See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/ for more info about Pipelines and PCollections, as well as some examples of simple pipelines

Comment: Thank you @danielm. you are right. I created an empty P collection using beam.Create() and it worked fine. Thanks for all your help.